# Spark function avg and BigDecimal's scale issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have this case class:

```
case class AllData(positionId: Long, warehouse: String, product: String, amount: BigDecimal, amountTime: Long)
```

and dataset:

```
val data: Dataset[AllData]
```

and this code:

```
 val statisticForAmounts = data.groupByKey(record => record.warehouse + ", " + record.product)
  .agg(
      max($"amount").as("maxAmount").as[BigDecimal],
      avg($"amount").as("avgAmount").as[BigDecimal]
   )
```

produces this schema:

```
root
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- maxAmount: decimal(38,18) (nullable = true)
 |-- avgAmount: decimal(38,22) (nullable = true)
```

Scale for avgAmount are bigger and causes issue, producing error

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot up cast `avgAmount` from decimal(38,22) to decimal(38,18) as it may truncate
The type path of the target object is:
- root class: "scala.math.BigDecimal"
```

I also tried to round data this way:

```
 val statisticForAmounts = data.groupByKey(record => record.warehouse + ", " + record.product)
  .agg(
   round(max($"amount"), 4).as("maxAmount").as[BigDecimal],
   round(avg($"amount"), 4).as("avgAmount").as[BigDecimal]
  )
```

This changed schema to:

```
root
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- maxAmount: decimal(38,4) (nullable = true)
 |-- avgAmount: decimal(38,4) (nullable = true)
```

And error this time was:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot up cast `maxAmount` from decimal(38,4) to decimal(38,18) as it may truncate
The type path of the target object is:
- root class: "scala.math.BigDecimal"
```

Why is it so and how can I prevent this from happen? I have Spark 2.4

Comment: `DecimalType(int precision, int scale)` I think average has more multiply and division operation and the scale could be larger than just a number, maximum. It seems that is natural.

Comment: @Lamanus But what can I do to avoid that errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seems to be the case is that the `avg` function adds another 4 slots to the decimal point to account for the increased need for scale when fractions are divided. The `DecimalType(38,18)` means you have 38 slots total and 18 slots past the decimal point (which leaves `38-18=20` for the area in front of the decimal point).

A much simpler way to think about it is that you have 20 slots to the left and 18 slots to the right so `DecimalType(38,18) = (20 left, 18 right)`. Similarly `DecimalType(38,22) = (16 left, 22 right)`.Of course it's impossible to shove a `(16,22)` into a `(20,18)` because 4 left-slots (i.e. decimal slots) will be lost (although you will have an additional 4 right slots).

Now, since the AVG function seems to add 4 slots to the left (i.e. the after decimal point) that's basically an operation of `(-4 right, +4 left)`. Once this odd process is complete, we are forced to cast a `(16 left, 22 right)` back to the standard `DecimalType(38,18)` i.e. `(20 left, 18 right)` since that's the Scala/Java default... and that's what fails since we'd need to chop-off (i.e. 'truncate') 4 slots on the right to do that.

So... we need to make sure the resulting number can actually fit into these slots. Thus, if we down-cast from `(20 left, 18 right)` to `(20 left, 14 right)` (i.e. `DecimalType(34, 14)`) from the get-go, the `(+0 right, +4 left)` will just bring us back to the `(20 left, 18 right)` that we're looking for. In other words, do this:

```
val averageableData = 
  data.withColumn("amount", $"amount".cast(DecimalType(34,14)))
```

Then, doing this should work:

```
averageableData.groupByKey(record => record.warehouse + ", " + record.product)
  .agg(
      max($"amount").as("maxAmount").as[BigDecimal],
      avg($"amount").as("avgAmount").as[BigDecimal]
   )
```

What is interesting is that you can actually cast to anything that is less than `(20 left, 14 right)`. That is to say, you can do `.cast(DecimalType(33, 13))` or anything less. When the `(+0 left, +4 right)` operation happens, it will still fit into a `(20 left, 18 right)`.